# How to convert ArrayBuffer to byte[]?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm reading a file from a `FileList` retrieved from `HTMLInputElement` and want to get the raw bytes out of `File#arrayBuffer()`. How do I do it?

```
import elemental2.core.ArrayBuffer;

public static byte[] toBytes(ArrayBuffer buffer) {
    // code in question
}
```

Comment: Is this an actual question? Is this actually a self-answer question? Do you have a question? Does your code not work?

Comment: Self-answer but better solutions are welcome

Comment: Consider editing your question to list the code that is causing a problem and a description of that problem.

Comment: @JohnH I've improved the question with a code skeleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that as long as you don't look too closely at it, a JS `Int8Array` (and so a `elemental2.core.Int8Array`) behaves like you'd expect a GWT/Java `byte[]` to do - it will only contain values from -127 to 128. Unlike a "real" `byte[]`, it will not correctly cast to `byte[]` and anything calling `.getClass()` or other Java methods on it will not work correctly either. It also can't be cast (by generics or explicitly) to `byte[]` either.

So if you need to treat the contents as a real Java array, you have to copy it first. Your answer will do what you want, but it might be more clearly correct to not "convert it from Double" along the way:

```java
import elemental2.core.ArrayBuffer;
import elemental2.core.Int8Array;
import jsinterop.base.Js;

public static byte[] toBytes(ArrayBuffer buffer) {
    // Use uncheckedCast since we are outright lying to the compiler
    byte[] arr = Js.uncheckedCast(new Int8Array(buffer));
    byte[] result = new byte[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your solution is also correct - a `java.lang.Double` in GWT and J2CL is exactly the same as a JS Number type, which is what your Int8Array is going to return when you query its values. The `byteValue()` call you're making will ask the compiler to make certain that the values are what is expected - it will truncate (probably via `value & 0xFF`?) the value, which should be cheap, but not entirely free.

Finally as long as you are just going to treat the resulting `byte[]` as a collection you can iterate, and won't be dealing with it in some way that the actual type will be checked, we can get away with not copying it at all:

```java
import elemental2.core.ArrayBuffer;
import elemental2.core.Int8Array;
import jsinterop.base.Js;

public static byte[] toBytes(ArrayBuffer buffer) {
    byte[] result = Js.uncheckedCast(new Int8Array(buffer));
    return result;
}
```

This really is cheating though, and has other downsides, like if the original buffer is modified the array will be changed too, and vice versa. But it is very fast!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got so far:

```java
import elemental2.core.ArrayBuffer;
import elemental2.core.Int8Array;

public static byte[] toBytes(ArrayBuffer buffer) {
    Int8Array arr = new Int8Array(buffer);
    byte[] result = new byte[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        Double elem = arr.getAt(i);
        result[i] = elem.byteValue();
    }
    return result;
}
```